# How do I sign AWS API requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, coffeescript, meteor

folks.

I've been working (well, just started) a web application that's going to be taking advantage of the book searching web API from Amazon Web Services.

My problem...is that in order to use their API, you have to sign all requests using a HMAC SHA hash, and append the signature hash to your query when you send it along to them.

I wrote some code last night, after reading what documentation I could get my hands on, and it seems that I'm improperly signing my requests to the AWS API using this hashing algorithm I'm supposed to be using.

Here's the code I am currently using for accessing their API, with any secret keys removed for my own security:

```
Meteor.methods

    "isbnSearch": (isbn) ->

        ts = encodeURIComponent(new Date().toISOString())

        reqArray = [
            "Service=AWSCommerceService",
            "Operation=ItemLookup",
            "ResponseGroup=Medium%2CImages",
            "IdType=ISBN",
            "Timestamp="+ts,
            "AWSAccessKeyId=<Access Key Here>",
            "ItemId="+isbn,
            "Version=2014-08-02"
        ]

        req = reqArray.sort().join('&')

        stringToSign = "Get\nwebservices.amazon.com\n/onca/xml\n" + req
        theHash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, "<Secret Key Here>").toString()
        request = req + "&Signature=" + theHash
        reqURL = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?" + request

        result = HTTP.get reqURL, (e, res) ->

            console.log res
```

I am using the AWSAccessKeyId given to me by AWS, and the secret key as well in respective places, I guess I am just hashing something wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The response I get from AWS is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ItemLookupErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2014-08-02/">
        <Error>
            <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
            <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
        </Error>
        <RequestId>3377bde5-a006-429d-a1f6-8c4faf1b8efc</RequestId>
    </ItemLookupErrorResponse>
```

Comment: I am facing this error. Can you share the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/rest-signature.html (Step 9) you need to encode all +'s and ='s in your signature. You don't seem to be doing that in your code.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using one of the existing Meteorite aws-sdk packages: https://atmospherejs.com/?q=aws

They add access to the AWS Node.js SDK.

You could also add the NPM Meteorite package (http://atmospherejs.com/package/npm) to access the AWS Node.js SDK.

Comment: that was my first thought as well, but the SDK doesn't seem to cover the commerce APIs